# Proving inequality for the floor function

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, inequality, reference-request

The floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $((x))$ are intimately linked in computing Dedekind sums - which led me the quest below.

My current interest lies in this:

**QUESTION.** Assume $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers. Is this inequality true?
$$\lfloor 3a\rfloor+\lfloor 3b\rfloor+\lfloor 3c\rfloor\geq
2\lfloor a\rfloor+2\lfloor b\rfloor+2\lfloor c\rfloor+\lfloor a+b+c\rfloor.$$

Comment: It's enough to assume $\{a,b,c\}\subset[0,1).$

Comment: Yes, very true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @MichaelRozenberg, we may assume $\{a,b,c\}\subset[0,1)$.

So write $a=\frac i3+\alpha$, $b=\frac j3+\beta$, $c=\frac k3+\gamma$, where $i\in\{0,1,2\}$, $j\in\{0,1,2\}$, $k\in\{0,1,2\}$, and
$\alpha\in[0,\frac13)$, $\beta\in[0,\frac13)$, $\gamma\in[0,\frac13)$. The LHS of your inequality is
$$\lfloor i+3\alpha\rfloor +\lfloor j+3\beta\rfloor+\lfloor k+3\gamma\rfloor=i+j+k,$$
while the RHS of your inequality is
$$\left\lfloor \frac{i+j+k}3 +\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right
\rfloor.$$ Now $0\le\alpha+\beta+\gamma<1$ so $i+j+k= \lfloor i+j+k+\alpha+\beta+\gamma\rfloor$. The inequality follows from the fact that $i+j+k\ge \frac{i+j+k}3$.

Comment: You may apply the pair of `\left` and `\right` modifiers to make `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` automagically adjust their size to the height of an expression between them. For example, `\lfloor\frac k3\rfloor` results in $$\lfloor\frac k3\rfloor$$ whilst `\left\lfloor\frac k3\right\rfloor` looks like $$\left\lfloor\frac k3\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thanks! I knew that for parentheses, brackets and braces but somehow didn't think it applied to delimiters like `\lfloor` and `\langle`

Comment: It also works for vertical bars. Additionally, it can be applied to a _single_ symbol, but then you need to add a phoney empty symbol (use a dot for it), which completes a pair delimiting an expression. Example (just for formatting; no mathematical sense implied): `\frac{\sqrt{1\times\frac 1x}}3 + \left.\frac xy\right|_{x=1}^5` makes $$\frac{\sqrt{1\times\frac 1x}}3 + \left.\frac xy\right|_{x=1}^5$$ The left-dot and right-bar delimit the x/y ratio, so the bar fits that ratio's height only, despite the left addend being higher.